# Road bike for a 10 day trip in the Pyrenees and French rivera and other questions

Tags: road-bike, equipment, long-distance

I am planning a 10 day trip covering roughly between 500 and 600 kilometers, starting in the Spanish Pyrenees and finishing in Nice.

What kind of bike do you recommend me for such a trip? Obviously I need something with gears since I am going to do a bit of cycling in the mountains. I prefer not to get a mountain bike because my idea is to keep the bike and use it in London for commuting.

My budget is in the £500 - £700 range and I would probably go for second hand since that way I can get something better. At this price range I cannot afford any fancy carbon frame ones. However, would I ideally want a carbon frame bike? I know they are much lighter but I obviously need to carry some stuff in saddles so I am not sure I want a super light one, do I?

Also, I'd be great if you give me any advice on saddles as I will need to get these as well.

Finally, is averaging 50-60 kilometers a day too much for 2 fit guys in their late 20s and early 30s? I am  more or less a seasoned rider although no expert and certainly not trained.

Cheers!

Comment: This overweight 63-year-old with post-polio can still manage 100K a day on reasonably flat ground.  30-ish guys in decent health should have no problem doing 50-60K if the hills aren't terrible.  (Ideal would be a light touring bike, but any road bike that can take a sturdy rack should do fine.  Don't worry that much about how much the bike weighs - the difference between fancy and "just decent" will be under 5 kilos.)

Comment: @Daniel R Hicks - why not post as an answer?

Comment: I'm too lazy to do that.  You have to scroll all the way to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: With no training in the mountains it'll be quite painful I suspect regardless of what bike you have.

Comment: I don't even think they sell carbon frames with rack mounts, although I'm sure somebody can prove me wrong.  Rack mounts will be essential for a 10 day trip.  Although if you're only going 60 km per day, you may not need to bring a whole lot, I would probably be beneficial to have at least a couple small panniers for things like clothes, food, and basic repair tools.

Comment: Important: Don't think you'll get away putting things in a rucksack and riding.. you'll regret doing that if you ignore this advice!!

Comment: Thank you for all your comments! Keep them coming. :) So far, I have concluded from them that I should go for an aluminum frame bike. I should probably check that I can mount a sturdy pannier rack on the back also. Is it essential to wear one of those shorts? What about the shoes, I've never riden with them. Regarding the seat, I thought I wouldn't worry too much and in case I don't find it comfy I can always put a gel thingy on top. BTW I do cycle to work almost every day and I actually have training going up mountains so I guess the fitness issue is settled.

Comment: You may want to invest in cycle shorts and (stiff-soled) cycle shoes, as they improve comfort on a long ride.  Probably not a good time to switch to clipless pedals, unless you have at least a month to train with them.  You might want to look into "mountain bike" shoes, or some other shoe with a reasonably stiff sole and tread suited to not go sliding off the pedals.

Comment: (Don't discount steel frames.  The best touring bikes are still steel framed.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With no training in the mountains it'll be quite painful I suspect regardless of what bike you have.

If it were me I'd just take my road bike with panniers containing a bit of food etc. My Trek 1.5 2011 cost between 500-700 quid and is, in my limited opinion a fantastic bike.

I can't say that's the best solution, but I'd confidently take my trek up those mountains. Might be worth getting with a triple chain ring (3 cogs at the front) otherwise you might really struggle if you've done no training.

Saddle wise you stick with what it comes with and get some decent cycling shorts. Remember to keep back some money for:

- Helmet
- Cycling shoes/pedals perhaps?
- Cycling sunglasses (think rims/easier for seeing)
- Lock
- Tools including cleaning stuff, pump, spare tubes etc.
- Lights
- Other things I haven't mentioned.

Good luck!! And get training, that'll make the biggest difference!

Comment: http://www.evanscycles.com/products/trek/15-c-h2-2013-road-bike-ec040343

It's £850 apparently.. sorry. There are similar models with not so good features that are probably almost as good.

Comment: I think he was using "saddles" to mean "saddle bags"/panniers.

Comment: Really quite jealous too!

Answer (score 1):

I think your two main criteria should be: **comfort** and **reliability**. On a tour, both of these factors have a big effect on your speed as well as your enjoyment.

With that in mind you should probably aim to get a steel (or possibly aluminium frame). The good news is that steel lasts well, so buying second hand is a good option. Obviously check for signs of rust before buying. Carbon is not usually considered a good choice for a touring bike.

Saddles are a personal preference thing. I suggest buying a cheap one of medium width and not too much padding. Make sure you give it a good try well in advance of the trip. If it doesn't work for you they're easy to change.

50-60km a day is probably fine, unless you aim to finish the day at a significantly higher altitude than the start. I've forgotten to take this into account when planning and ended up quite cold camping in the mountains!

Comment: What about this bike? Any good for the job at hand? http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/200900694022?ssPageName=STRK:MEWAX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1423.l2649

Comment: OR this other one? http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/200901109512?ssPageName=STRK:MEWAX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1423.l2649

Comment: Well I don't think you could fit racks on either of those. I'd suggest something more like: http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Orbit-Touring-racing-bike-mudguards-ideal-touring-or-commuter-Reynolds-501-/140914427285?pt=UK_Bikes_GL&hash=item20cf278595 or http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Dawes-Galaxy-touring-bike-good-condition-for-age-/160977835906?pt=UK_Bikes_GL&hash=item257b06d782

Comment: Ok, thank you. I am starting to understand more the difference between a touring bike and road bike. What about the Cannondale Tesoro Traveller Classic 2010. I can get one with a load of gear and almost no use for 500.Is the fact that this is an American brand a drawback in terms of getting spares, fixing, etc.